# FullCalendar 5 passing classes from the server side

Tags: java, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to add classes to my Event in FullCalendar version 5. When I pass to classNames:

```
cssItalic
```

It works. However when I pass:

```
["cssItalic"]
```

I does not work (i.e., the Title is not italicised). I have also tried:

```
['cssItalic']
```

I have noticed that many questions/answers on this use className (i.e., without the 's').

The reason I need to resolve this is that I want to pass more than one css, for instance:

```
["cssItalic", "cssUnderline"]
```

I am using MySQL and java on the server side and passing as JSON. For this test I am using the code below:

```
String cssString2 = "[\'cssItalic\']";

CalendarEvent calendarEventDtls = new CalendarEvent(
    encoded_pat_id,
    result.getString("name"),
    result.getString("daysOfWeek"),
    result.getString("stt_start_date"),
    result.getString("stt_end_date"),
    result.getString("stt_start_time"),
    result.getString("stt_end_time"),
    result.getString("stt_colour"),
    cssString2,
    encoded_stt_id,
    result.getString("icon"));
calendarEventList.add(calendarEventDtls);
```

Where cssString2 is what ever I am trying to test:

```
String cssString2 = "[\"cssItalic\"]";
String cssString2 = "[\'cssItalic\']";
String cssString2 = "[cssItalic]";
String cssString2 = "cssItalic";
String cssString2 = "[\'cssItalic\', \'csscssUnderline\']";
```

Everything else is working as I expect.

Comment: Not reproducible - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ExwEJqd . If you can provide a [mre] of this issue in practice, we can perhaps assist further. Just the isolated snippets you've shown do not, by themselves, demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @ADyson This is my sample code; however, it is client side not server side. My issue is with passing the parameter from server side and I do not know how to reproduce that in an example. https://codepen.io/Glyndwr/pen/RwLJbvR

Comment: Ok, so please update the question to show how, currently you're passing that value from the server-side - clearly something is not right, but there isn't enough detail. I don't even know what server-side language you're using! Presumably you are getting the server-side  to output the string `["cssItalic"]` somehow into the fullcalendar config, but it isn't doing it the way you expected. Can you show the code you're using for that, in context?

Comment: What language is it? C#? Java? Please add a tag. Anyway, given you're building an object in the server-side code, I expect you should actually add the value as an array (contaning one string) in that language. Then it, along with the other values, it will all get JSON-encoded together when the event is output. I suspect if you look at what the final JSON of the event looks like with your current code, you'd probably observe that the cssString has been double-encoded, and that's probably why it's failing.